# Is it ok to maintain a website as the Git master not a bare repo?

Tags: git, deployment

I have seen quite a few entries about using bare Git repos above document root and hooks to push deploy websites but I need to keep changes made to the website by the host and pull my changes from a local copy.  This is because I installed Prestashop CMS using my host's 1-click install which also manages minor updates, clones and backup restores which is useful. Push deploy with hooks assumes I have the master offsite so the approach seems upside down for what I need. Also because of the MySQL db it's not that handy to keep master locally, on Bitbucket or the like without fiddling about.

My plan was to.. (from www/subfolder)

```
 $> git --git-dir=../../git/prestashop.git --work-tree=. init
```

But I haven't done this before or read about anyone else that has. Is a safe way to manage a production site? The .git files wouldn't be public and I could pull changes rather than push them and use SSH to issue git commands.

Or if I do go with the flow and use the bare repo method is it possible to keep the hosts minor software updates to Prestashop?

I'm fairly new to tracking, still a little gitslexic and used to my old school ftp workflow so any advice would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefer to have the repo in a separate directory and rsync or similar to the production directory, although I have used git directories directly as you're considering it, without any real trouble. The only issue I've run into is when a configuration file gets into the repo and replaces production configuration with dev. This can be easily avoided with .gitignore or similar though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on the right track then with some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into deploying your website with [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) - it will allow you to deploy out to a website in all sorts of manners, including from a git repository (which is the most common way) and include any type of workflow, including doing a pull remotely.

As well, there is no reason you could not do as you say, I often start with a very basic pull strategy then migrate to capistrano once I know the project needs to be maintained.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look at Capistrano.